# Using AbstractExcelView from a portlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, portlet

how can i use spring AbstractExcelView to generate a excel file in a portlet

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

See the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-document-configsubclasses).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. My requirement is to incorporate it to a jsr-168 portlet. how to achieve that ?

Comment: I don't know much about Portlets with Spring, but according to the docs it sounds like you can use the same AbstractExcelView: "Spring Portlet MVC directly reuses all the view technologies from Spring Web MVC. This includes not only the various View implementations themselves, but also the ViewResolver implementations."